# Show Context Actions (alt + enter) not showing for some class names in a Flutter Project (trying to import a reference)

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea

When trying to import a reference in a Flutter project some class / functions are no longer showing the context actions menu (alt+enter) but some are

For example alt+enter on `StatefulWidget` doesn't do anything but alt+enter on `Widget` does.

*Flutter specific things I've tried: flutter clean, deleted my .pubspec.lock, .dart_tool & .packages files, rerun analysis*

*intellij things I've tried: invalidated indexes and restarted)*

**Edit**

In the following code snippet if I try to do the alt+enter on the StatelessWidget class inside the build method I do get the context action but if I try it in the extends I don't get the context action.

```
class Blah extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(context) => //
      StatelessWidget();
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors/warning in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: thanks, it seems there are many warns and infos there, a couple of errors but I don't understand most of it tbh

Comment: jediterm.terminal.TerminalMode - Mode EightBitInput is not implemented, setting to true - one of the few errors

Comment: Same problem with intellij.